# MVC ExecuteQuery not a valid method on Context object

Tags: model-view-controller, executequery

I am trying to execute a sql command directly against the database. However, intellisense does not see ExecuteQuery as a valid method against my context variable. I am sure I am missing something obvious.

My context class:

```
 public class CatastropheContext : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<CLIENT> CLIENTs { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

My attempt to establish the query:

```
CatastropheContext db = new CatastropheContext();
IEnumerable<ClientClaim> = db.ExecuteQuery
```

In the code above, ExecuteQuery is flagged as invalid an intellisense suggests creating a stub method.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use Database.ExecuteSqlCommand where Database comes from the DbContext class.

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand does not show as a valid method under Database. I did include "using System.Data.Entity" to no avail.

Comment: It looks like I can use db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand, so perhaps I am gtg. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like you are missing some references. Make sure you are:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

[Here is the MSDN reference on ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx). Notice the namespace.

Comment: If there are additional details I could provide, please let me know and I will post them.

Comment: That did not answer my question :) Do you have that using statement?

Comment: I did *not* have that using statement. However, adding it made no difference. I did find that: db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand is valid, so perhaps I am gtg. Thanks for your assist!